# Expression method for NULLIF (with Divide)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, expression-trees

I am using C# 4.5.2. I Have to call a `SumDenominator` method as a denominator for an `Expression.Divide` method:

```
var SumDenominatorExpression = Expression.Call(
    null,
    SumDenominatorMethod,
    Parameter,
    SumDenominatorSelector
);
```

then later on the actual `Expression.Divide` reads:

```
var FractionExpression = Expression.Divide(
    SumNumeratorExpression,
    SumDenominatorExpression
);
```

if the denominator's selector generates zero then the divide by zero exception is thrown. I tried to solve this by converting the `Sum` expression into a `Nullable<>` but the Divide method doesn't swallow null values. And the SQLServer (my provider) doesn't have a `NULLIF` function (i.e. System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions) that I can wrap a Call expression around.

How to people tackle zeros in the denominator with C# Expression trees?

**UPDATE**
Here are the expression methods I ended up using:

```
 Expression.Condition(
   Expression.Equal(
     SumDenominatorExpression,
     Expression.Constant(0.0, typeof(double))
   ),
   Expression.Constant(0.0, typeof(double)),
   FractionExpression
 )
```

Comment: I don't really get how you solve the divby0 problem: by default C# will throw a divby0exception, what is the behavior in such case you aim at?

Comment: Expression.Divide disallows nulls in the denominator but SQL Server allows nulls with SQL, thus the question how to work a NULLIF function from EF.

Comment: Ah, ok. I've probably translated it the wrong way (in Dutch, *nul* means zero) therefore it is a bit confusing. Sorry.

Comment: @CommuSoft, Easy miss. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want EF to be able to translate this expression. That restricts the kinds of patterns we can use. The following should work:

```
FractionExpression =
  (SumDenominatorExpression == 0)
     ? (int?)null /*default value - pick what you want*/
     : (SumNumeratorExpression / SumDenominatorExpression);
```

(I'm writing the expression tree as C# for typing speed.)

Since EF does not support trees that have variables you will need to use the `SumDenominatorExpression` expression twice. Hopefully SQL Server will optimize that and evaluate it only once.

Comment: Evaluating **SumDenominatorExpression** (i.e. a call expression) equal to zero as an C# Expression?  That is the interesting part...

Comment: What do you mean by that? Does this answer the question?

Comment: @MatthewYoung That's what `Expression.Equal()` is for.

Comment: @usr, Updated my question with the resulting code from your answer.  Thanks.